# OnTriggerExit2D getting called unnecessarily

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I hope you all are doing well. I have been following a Unity tutorial for a rhythm game and I have found this bug that I could not get past. Essentially, my OnTriggerExit2D is getting called too early. I'll include a picture in the conclusion of this post. I have tried logging the game object and it seems that all of my button objects suffer the same fate. I have included a link of the tutorial that I have been following in the conclusion. Any help towards figuring this out would be helpful.

Tutorial Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfhS-kEvc0&ab_channel=gamesplusjames

What my game looks like, the missed shows up when I've hit it.
[image: I've hit the note within range, but missed still shows.]

Debug Output
[image: Debug Output]

GameManager

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource theMusic;
    public bool startPlaying;
    public BeatScroller theBS;
    public static GameManager instance;

    public int currentScore;
    public int scorePerNote = 100;
    public int scorePerGoodNote = 125;
    public int scorePerPerfectNote = 150;
    
    public int currentMultiplier;
    public int multiplierTracker;
    public int [] multiplierTresholds;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text multiText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;

        scoreText.text = "Score: 0";
        multiText.text = "Multiplier: x1";
        currentMultiplier = 1;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
     if(!startPlaying){
         if(Input.anyKeyDown){
             startPlaying = true;
             theBS.hasStarted = true;
             theMusic.Play();
         }
     }
    }

    public void NoteHit(){
        Debug.Log("Note Hit On Time");
        if(currentMultiplier-1 < multiplierTresholds.Length){

        multiplierTracker++;

            if(multiplierTresholds[currentMultiplier-1] <= multiplierTracker){
                multiplierTracker = 0;
                currentMultiplier++;
            }
        }

        multiText.text = "Multiplier: x"+currentMultiplier;

        //currentScore += scorePerNote * currentMultiplier;
        scoreText.text = "Score: "+currentScore;
    }

    public void NormalHit(){
        currentScore += scorePerNote * currentMultiplier;
        NoteHit();
    }

    public void GoodHit(){
        currentScore += scorePerGoodNote * currentMultiplier;
        NoteHit();

    }

    public void PerfectHit(){
        currentScore += scorePerPerfectNote * currentMultiplier;
        NoteHit();
 
    }

    public void NoteMissed(){
        Debug.Log("MISSED!");
        multiText.text = "Multiplier: x1";
    }
}
```

BeatScroller

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BeatScroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float beatTempo;
    public bool hasStarted;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        beatTempo = beatTempo / 60f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!hasStarted){
           
        }else{
            transform.position -= new Vector3(0f, beatTempo*Time.deltaTime, 0f);
        }            
    }
}
```

ButtonController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private SpriteRenderer theSR;
    public Sprite defaultImage;
    public Sprite pressedImage;

    public KeyCode keyToPress;
    void Start()
    {
        theSR = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(keyToPress))
        {
            theSR.sprite = pressedImage;
        }

         if(Input.GetKeyUp(keyToPress))
        {
            theSR.sprite = defaultImage;
        }
    }
}
```

noteObject

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class noteObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool canBePressed;
    public KeyCode KeyToPress;
    public GameObject hitEffect, goodEffect, perfectEffect, missedEffect;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyToPress))
        {
            if(canBePressed)
            {
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
                if(Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y) > 0.25){
                    GameManager.instance.NormalHit();
                    Debug.Log("Normal Hit!");
                    Instantiate(hitEffect,transform.position, hitEffect.transform.rotation);
                }else if(Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y) > 0.05f){
                    GameManager.instance.GoodHit();
                    Debug.Log("Good Hit!!");
                    Instantiate(goodEffect,transform.position, goodEffect.transform.rotation);
                }else{
                    GameManager.instance.PerfectHit();
                    Debug.Log("PERFECT HIT!!!");
                    Instantiate(perfectEffect,transform.position, perfectEffect.transform.rotation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Activator")
        {
            canBePressed = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Activator")
        {
            Debug.Log("Exited collider on game object: "+ other.gameObject.name);
            canBePressed = false;
            GameManager.instance.NoteMissed();
            Instantiate(missedEffect,transform.position, missedEffect.transform.rotation);

        }
    }
}
```

EffectObject

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EffectObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lifeTime = 1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       Destroy(gameObject, lifeTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in general: Why do you call `Destroy` in `EffectObject.Update`? Should only be done once.. Then if you say it is called to early .. when would you expect it? And when would you not? Might it happen because according object is destroyed?

Comment: The Destroy method is for the particle effect that appears alongside the instantiation in the noteObject class. It instantiates the effect object based off the type of hit and it deletes the effect afterwards.

Comment: If you watch the tutorial it will show you how that works [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oi0tT7QnFhs&ab_channel=gamesplusjames)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... You say that `OnTriggerExit2D` is called to early? I assume it's called when the elements are still inside one another? If that's the case I guess your bounding boxes don't have the right size, or the right shape. I see arrows, do they have a rectangular bounding box or a polygon one that follows their shape? Are all your bounding boxes the right size?

Comment: You say that OnTriggerExit2D is called to early? - It's more of calling the missed message just as the arrow enters one of the button areas, but I still have the ability to register the arrow as a hit because the arrow didn't travel below the colored buttons. 

The Arrows have **CircleCollider2Ds** and the color buttons have **BoxCollider2Ds** & **Rigibody2D** I will add pictures of the set up to this post. Thank You So Much Again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong thanks to AdrAs's comment.

Turns out I had to check the y position of my arrow and collider were well enough below the height of my button box collider. In addition to that, I reshaped my colliders. I found that this code did the trick for me. Thank You All For the Nudges in the right direction.

noteObject -> new OnTriggerExit2D

```
 private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Activator" && transform.position.y < -0.32)
        {
            Debug.Log("Exited collider on game object: "+ other.gameObject.name);
            canBePressed = false;
            GameManager.instance.NoteMissed();
            Instantiate(missedEffect,transform.position, missedEffect.transform.rotation);

        }
    }
```